# Aggregating data in BigQuery by month

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I feel silly asking this because it seems simple, but I concede and need some help. In BigQuery I have a Table that looks like this:

| Date | Portfolio | Super_Discipline | Dollars | Units |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-05-20 | Mathematics | Precalculus | 546.99 | 46 |
| 2020-01-06 | Mathematics | Calculus | 232.80 | 27 |
| 2019-08-10 | Professional | IT | 53.99 | 19 |
| 2019-01-15 | Science | Biol | 862.24 | 99 |

What I'm trying to accomplish is groupby month. So I'm looking to create a table that has each portfolio and super discipline and month (date) uniquely in a row with the sales and units for that month and those attributes summed up.

If it helps, if I was in Python I would simply replace the Date column with the months and then type `df.groupby(['Portfolio','Super_Discipline']).sum().reset_index()`

I think my biggest issue is that the date column is in days, so when I convert it with "FORMAT_DATE('%Y-%m', Date) AS Date" I can't groupby it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below

```
select format_date('%Y-%m', Date) as month, 
 Portfolio, 
 Super_Discipline, 
 sum(Dollars) as Dollars, 
 sum(Units) as Units
from your_table
group by month, Portfolio, Super_Discipline
```